# Matrix.Multiply in System.Drawing.Drawing2D works... differently?

Tags: c#, matrix, graphics

```
Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
matrix1.Multiply(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 200));

matrix1.Elements.ToList().ForEach(f => Console.Write(f + " "));
Console.WriteLine();

matrix1.Multiply(new Matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0));

matrix1.Elements.ToList().ForEach(f => Console.Write(f + " "));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.ReadKey();
```

Just for the record, since last column of matrix always equals to (0, 0, 1), matrices in Matrix2D are stored as (m11 m12 m21 m22 offsetx offsety)

From what I know, matrix multiplication works like the following:

```
[1   0   0]   [2 0 0]   [2   0   0]
[0   1   0] * [0 2 0] = [0   2   0]
[100 200 1]   [0 0 1]   [200 400 1]
```

So can anyone explain the following results of the presented program?

```
1 0 0 1 100 200
2 0 0 2 100 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wf86e5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains that the default multiplication order is to *prepend* the given matrix. Thus your last multiplication in fact looks like this:

```
[2 0 0]   [1   0   0]    [2   0   0]
[0 2 0] * [0   1   0]  = [0   2   0]
[0 0 1]   [100 200 1]    [100 200 1]
```

So it's the other way around, and the printed console result is correct.

To achieve your expected result you could use the [`Matrix.Multiply Method (Matrix, MatrixOrder)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8fss9w5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload and give `MatrixOrder.Append` as the second argument.